# Send a message or notification to other user within the site

Tags: 7, users, notifications

I'm using Drupal 7 on a production site and I want users to be notified by email and if they are on the site at the time, in a message window that they have been awarded points or other notifications. I already know how to do the email part, I just use the rules module to accomplish this. But I'm at a lost about how to do this with messaging, I tried using rules to create a site message but the message is only visible to the user that "granted" the points not the "recipient".